# Fetch expanded_url from a twitter user using tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

```
def get_latest_tweet():
  usertweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='user',count='1',tweetmode="extended") [0]
  print (usertweet.urls)

get_latest_tweet()
```

So far i've tried using "usertweet.expanded_url" instead of "usertweet.urls" but, I'm still getting the same error of

```
'Status' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

although

```
print(usertweet.text)
```

is working fine

**UPDATE :-** expanded url is inside entities/url section

```
 urls=(jypetweet.entities["urls"])
  print(urls)
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
[{'url': 'https://twit.co/PcgY0E5qM', 'expanded_url': 'https://live.tv/video/17615', 'display_url': 'live.tv/video/17615', 'indices': [107, 130]}]
```

But i'm still not able to access urls part

Comment: Hi @shivam-sah did you find a solution and where you able to access the expanded_url of tweepy ?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to figure it out, not the most cleanest of solution though..

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was the original code :-**

```
def get_latest_tweet():
  jypetweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='jypetwice',count='1',tweetmode="extended") [0]
  urls=(jypetweet.entities["urls"])
  rem_brackets= str(urls)[1:-1]
  res = ast.literal_eval(rem_brackets)
  tweet_url=res[0]['expanded_url']
  print (tweet_url)
```

**This was the second edit :-**

```
def get_latest_tweet():
  jypetweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='jypetwice',count='1',tweetmode="extended") [0]
  urls=(jypetweet.entities["urls"])
  tweet_url=urls[0]["expanded_url"]
  print(tweet_url)
```

**This is the final code :-**

```
def get_latest_tweet():
  jypetweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='jypetwice',count='1',tweetmode="extended") [0]
  urle=(jypetweet.entities["urls"][0]["expanded_url"])
  print (urle)
```

Comment: expandedURL = follows.entities["url"]["urls"][0]["expanded_url"] worked for me